# Unity Android Build Error: Failed to re-package resources

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, build, facebook-unity-sdk

I have been trying to crack this for hours now. I'm trying to build to my Samsung S8 which is running Android 7.0 (SDK 24) but I am getting the build error failed to repackage resources. Here is the full error below:

(I'm sorry for huge wall of error but I don't fully understand it and I've tried a lot of suggestions from the site to no avail.)

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.C:\Users\lewey\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\25.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/Users/lewey/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages`
`android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview:android.support.customtabs:com.facebook.android:com.facebook.applinks:com.facebook.common:com.facebook.core:com.facebook.login:com.facebook.messenger:com.facebook.places:com.facebook.share:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\animated-vector-drawable-25.3.1\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cardview-v7-25.3.1\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\customtabs-25.3.1\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-wrapper-7.11.0\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-applinks\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-common\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-core\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-login\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-messenger\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-places\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-share\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-compat-25.3.1\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-ui-25.3.1\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-core-utils-25.3.1\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-fragment-25.3.1\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-media-compat-25.3.1\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-25.3.1\res" -S "E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-vector-drawable-25.3.1\res"`

`stderr[
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml:17: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <ImageView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml:17: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <ImageView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_action_mode_close_item_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/abc_action_mode_close_item_material for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:scrollIndicators from <ScrollView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:26: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml:45: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <android.support.v7.widget.DialogTitle>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml:36: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <ImageView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_title_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/abc_alert_dialog_title_material for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_dialog_title_material.xml:29: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <TextView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_dialog_title_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/abc_dialog_title_material for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout.xml:24: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <TextView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml:59: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <ImageView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/abc_popup_menu_item_layout for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:touchscreenBlocksFocus from <android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/abc_screen_toolbar for configuration v21.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_search_view.xml:47: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_search_view.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/abc_search_view for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_select_dialog_material.xml:23: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <view>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\abc_select_dialog_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/abc_select_dialog_material for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-common\res\layout\com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:80: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <TextView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-common\res\layout\com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:80: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-common\res\layout\com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-common\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:94: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-common\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:94: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <TextView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-common\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:83: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-common\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:83: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <TextView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-common\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:47: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-common\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\notification_action.xml:17: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <LinearLayout>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\notification_action.xml:32: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <TextView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\notification_action.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/notification_action for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\notification_action_tombstone.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <LinearLayout>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\notification_action_tombstone.xml:37: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <TextView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout\notification_action_tombstone.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/notification_action_tombstone for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media.xml:42: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentEnd from <include>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/notification_template_big_media for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:89: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <LinearLayout>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <LinearLayout>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:56: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <FrameLayout>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:45: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <FrameLayout>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:45: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <FrameLayout>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media_custom.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentEnd from <include>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media_custom.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.LewisSeddon.BaseBuild:layout/notification_template_big_media_custom for configuration v17.
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:60: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <ImageView>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <LinearLayout>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
E:\Projects\BaseBuild\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-25.3.1\res\layout-v11\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the weirdest fix for this using this youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiuopHaSYHM

All I had to do was cut and paste the 24.0.0 build tools somewhere else as they must be broken with Unity and now it works perfectly!